# What's the height of the iPhone 6+' navigation bar?

Tags: iphone

With the new size and resolution of the iPhone 6+', including the different (CSS) pixel ratio (Retina HD: 3:1), I was wondering if the navigation bar height has changed.

Is it still 88px and thus the content area has grown, or has it adapted and does it have (in ratio) the same height, thus 132px in height?

Or.. Anyway: What's the size of the iPhone 6+' navigation bar?

See also: [The iOS 7 design cheat sheet](http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-7-design-cheat-sheet/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The navigation bar height has stayed the same and only thing that has changed is the amount of screen real estate available for extra content underneath the navigation bar.

Hope that answers your question :)

Comment: Pretty much as I thought. So it stayed 88px, but because of the higher DPI it just looks smaller :) Thanks

Comment: No, it should be 44@3x, not 88px.